# Why didn't Danzo get the Rinnegan?

Tags: naruto

In Naruto, it was said that you need both Senju and Uchiha DNA to achieve Rinnegan, right? So why didn't Danzo get Rinnegan? He had Senju DNA holding Uchiha DNA.

Comment: The question is, does he knew that Rinnegan exists in Nagato?

Comment: @NaraShikamaru the question is completely dependent on what u said. But this can be considered as a different question!

Comment: Did Danzo really have the Uchiha DNA? I doubt that. Are there any references for it?

Comment: @R.J I have a question here. DNA can be taken even from a person's hair, which means it can be taken from eye also. Since danzo was able to control the sharingans, he had them connected with his body. Doesn't it mean he had DNA's of uchiha?? Please clarify :)

Comment: @RikuduSennin - Yeah it can be taken from the hair, but not the eye. Even kakashi was able to control Obito's Sharingan, but that doesn't mean he had the Uchiha DNA. I really feel that by just having a Sharingan gives you the Uchiha DNA.

Comment: every cell in ur body contains dna

Comment: @lordnamikaze, yes every cell in your body contains a DNA but combining someone's DNA to another is a different issue. It requires complex process (in Genetics) and consumes a lot of experiment to achieve the combination of two DNA's in one body thus having the Uchihas' eyes doesn't give you the Uchiha DNA right R.J?

Answer (score 9):

Well, that's becasue you also need to be competent enough to master both these powers.

Madara was strong enough, and was able to awaken it. Danzo however, was not.

Danzo's DNA originates from experiments and body modifications. He wasn't a "Natural", while Madara had natural mastery over the Uchiha powers, and after being defeated by Hashirama, mastery over the Senju powers.

It was also implied that you need to be very close to the end of your lifespan to awaken the Rinnegan.

---

### Edit - Spoilers!

> Based on the recent chapters, it is implied that it isn't Senju + Uchiha which is needed to awaken the Rinnegan, but Indra's and Ashura's (Sage of Six Paths' sons) chakras. That is why Madara (the incarnation of Indra) was able to awaken them after implanting Hashirama's (the incarnation of Ashura) cells into his wounds.

Comment: Nagato awakened it early. obviously he was pretty good with Sharringan, he used Isanagi.

Comment: @user2799 Nagato was implanted with the rinnegan when he was young by Madara. Also he never used Isanagi. The only shinobis that was shown using isanagi was Tobi and Danzo.

Comment: Did Danzo really have the Uchiha DNA? I doubt that. Are there any references for it?

Comment: He did have Sharingans, you know

Comment: yea and I meant danzo used isanagi. nagato was given a sharringan, he unlocked rinnegan cause he was already uzumaki.

Comment: @user2799: Nagato was given a Rinnegan from childhood. Danzo had Hashirama's DNA plus the Uchiha's Sharingans, hence he was able to use Izanagi. I don't understand your question.

Comment: @madara, the idea is that both senju and uchiha dna unlock rinnegan, right? hence madara achieved it in his fight with hishiroma, and nagato.... idk some say he was given a sharringan in his youth, others say he may have been naturally both clans(uzumaki is genetically tied to the senju). danzo had senju dna implanted to hold the sharringans (uchiha dna). so y weren't those all rinnegans?

Comment: @user2799: Because he wasn't strong enough/smart enough/"potent" enough to awaken them. In addition to having both Uchiha and Senju powers, one needs to aptitude to awaken the Rinnegan. Also, the Rinnegan was 100% transplanted into Nagato as a young child, that much was explicitely said in the manga.

Comment: so pretty much danzo was a punk??

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - Danzo only has the Sharingans. That do not count as Uchiha DNA. He used Hashirama's cells in his body(hand to be precise) to keep the Sharingans. Just having the eye doesn't mean having the DNA and that's the reason he never could have awakened the Rinnegan. If just having the Sharingan means having Uchiha DNA, then why wasn't Kakashi able to turn of the Sharingan? That's because only with the Sharingan blood, you get the ability to turn off and on the Sharingan.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha - You can say that Obito wasn't *strong enough/smart enough/"potent"* enough to awaken the Rinnegan, despite having the Uchiha blood and the Senju DNA. That's why he took the Rinnegan from Nagato's corpse. :)

Comment: @R.J, I think madara mentioned about danzo not strong enough to awaken rinnegan. Btw, Does obito have senju DNA??

Comment: @RikuduSennin - Ofcourse he does. When Madara found him, the right side of body was completely damaged. It was reconstructed it using Hashirama's living clone(which Madara had created). Therefore, Obito technically has half body of an Uchiha and the rest half of a Senju.

Comment: @RikuduSennin - Can you give me the reference of that(where Madara mentions about Danzo not being strong enough to awaken Rinnegan)? Because I firmly believe that Danzo never had the Uchiha DNA with him.

Comment: hair, spit, yes even the eye would count as dna

Answer (score 1):

Danzo didn't awaken a Rinnegan because he is not a reincarnation of Indra. Even if he did, he only has the chakra reserves for like one or two moves. The manga and anime state that in order to awaken the Rinnegan without means of transplantation, one must possess a Sharingan, be Indra's reincarnate, take chakra from Ashura's reincarnate (**these are Hagoromo, the Sage of Six Paths two sons)** thus reforming Hagoromo's chakra, leading to the Rinnegan awakening. If a non-Indra reincarnate does what Danzo did, all he would get is Izanagi-spam, lesser cooldown on Kotoamatsukami wait, and Mokuton (wood style.)

Put simply, Danzo didn't awaken a Rinnegan because he isn't an Indra reincarnate.

Just in case you still don't understand, here's an image from the manga when **Hagoromo himself** explains how Madara awakened the Rinnegan.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Danzo was not able to awaken the rinnegan because he had senju DNA and Uchiha eyes but had neither enough chakra to effectively utilize either ability (hashirama' s wood style or the sharingan in his arms). While madara was an Uchiha who implanted hashirama's DNA throughout his whole body he did not awaken the rinnegan until he was near death. It would not be expected for someone like Danzo to be capable of manifesting the rinnegan, at least at the point in time that he was living.

Answer (score 0):

Like many said, you kinda need the "blood" or "chakra" of the Uchiha and Senju to awakened, which many stated to be implied at the end of one's life. Danzo doesn't have any, only body modifications. Danzo had the Sharingan because he STOLE them, he ripped them out of the Uchiha who had them, therefore he will never awaken the Rinnegan. That's why he was bandaged, so it doesn't drain his chakra. It's not that Madara was strong enough, he basically had the requirements to do so, just at the end of his life did it awakened.

Nagato was implanted the Rinnegan at a early age by Madara before he died, and Nagato is of the Uzumaki, hence how he could easily handle the Rinnegan (I am sure if he had both Rinnegan or just the one).

Answer (score 0):

Also, you need an EMS to evolve into the rinnegan unless you were born with it, which hagoromo was.We all know that even if you have senju and uchiha blood, you need the EMS to evolve into rinnegan. If hashirama wanted the rinnegan, he would have to transplant madara's sharingan to get it. If someone was the descendant of an incarnate of indra and also an incarnate of asura, he would be able to awaken the Sharingan, just the sharingan unless he was an incarnate of Asura.